# General inquiry about best way to integrate a DB into an Android App

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I'm doing an assignment in my Android Development class and I need to have access to a database in the app, I wanted to use SQLite as there is plenty of resources out there on this topic but all the storage is local, so what i need to know is, what is the best way to implement a remote database?

I have seen a few things that store info locally then uploads to a MySQL database once an active connection is available, is this the best way to do it?

Is it possible to have a remote version of SQLite, how is this done?

Any links to resources will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you can use Remote server to store your data and fetch that data using API.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use DriverManager#getConnection(url, username, password) like usual. 
Make sure you do `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` and make sure you have the SQLite jar in your classpath (you can get it [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc)).

An example is below:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection thisIsYourDBConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://url", "username", "password");
```

btw MySQL is so much better than SQLite